# MacOS / Outlook 2016 - Reading Pane no longer shows any attachments

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I have a MacOS Macbook pro (late 2012 i believe) that is running Outlook 2016 as part of an Office 365 subscription.

An update installed ~24 hours ago.

We have just noticed that the reading pane in the main outlook window no longer shows attached files.

Below is an example email viewed on a Windows 10 device with access to the same mailbox, you can see the attachments in the email header

[image: Attached Example of how we would expect it to appear]

When viewing this email on the Mac we do not see the attachments at all. If the email is opened all attachments display as you would expect.

I've tested sent mail to the Mac as HTML/Rich Text/Plain Text and the same happens on each.

I've dug through the view options on the Mac and thoroughly bashed google but can't find anything mentioning this issue.

The obvious option is to roll back the update but I'd prefer to fix in place than do that if possible.

Comment: Can you see the attachment if we open the message in a separate window instead of viewing in Reading Pane?

Comment: Yes, the view is as expected when the email is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You may hit a known issue. See a similar thread which has been confirmed by a MS guy: [Outlook for Mac 2016 (march 2017 update - version 15.32 (170309)) - email attachments disappering](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/outlook-for-mac-2016-march-2017-update-version/bcb2c2b8-26db-4b78-80a4-03f96d61ee5e)

Try installing the latest update and see whether the issue will disappear. If not, you may also try latest insider version if necessary.

Comment: It was the most recent update that appears to have caused it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was still happening to me in 2022. The [Microsoft support thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-for-mac-2016-march-2017-update-version/bcb2c2b8-26db-4b78-80a4-03f96d61ee5e) that was linked from the [other answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-for-mac-2016-march-2017-update-version/bcb2c2b8-26db-4b78-80a4-03f96d61ee5e) was indeed helpful, but not the part that was mentioned in the other answer regarding updating Outlook.

Instead, these steps from the thread helped me. I copied them here to preserve them in case something happens to the Microsoft thread:

```
1. Quit Outlook
2. Open Terminal 
3. Type the command “defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook DisableAppCommand_Support -bool YES”
4. Type the command “killall cfprefsd”
5. Launch Outlook for Mac
```